# What's a good Login Auth flow

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

How would I implement a solution like described below? Would it be easier to jack in something like ember-simple-auth? All examples I find implement their own login form, that's not something I'll have. My login will live on its own domain.

Scenario:

1. user visits https://myapp.com.
2. In some initializer I see that they don't have an/don't have a valid access token so I redirect them to https://login.myapp.com?redirect_uri=https://myapp.com
3. login.myapp.com sign the user in hand hands them an access token and redirects user to https://myapp.com?access_token={token}
4. Myapp boots again only this time it finds a valid access token (from the url) and sets some variable that the user is logged in. And then adds the token as header bearer onto all future xhr requests.

Is this a logical login approach? Some fundamental flaws I'm missing? Do you know any tutorials doing something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That flow would be pretty easy to implement with Ember Simple Auth. You simply need to [define a custom authenticator](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authenticator) that you authenticate the session with when the application starts up again after the redirect. The authenticator's `authenticate` method would look sth. like this:

```
authenticate: function(options) {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve({ token: /* the token you get from the query string */ });
  });
}
```

Authenticating the session with the authenticator in an initializer then is as easy as:

```
this.get('session').authenticate('your-authenticator');
```